# Does the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt n (\tan x)^n$ for $x \in (-\pi/4,\pi/4)$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt n (\tan x)^n$$ for $x \in (-\pi/4,\pi/4)$ converges. I am trying to use the Abel Criteria but I have no luck. Could someone offer a tip to the right direction?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. To make progress, set $q = \tan x$. What can you say about $q$ if $-\pi/4 < x < \pi/4$?

Comment: q∈(−1,1). I understand that the n-th root of the absolute price of the sequence is less than 1, which implies that the sequence converges. However, I’m struggling to prove that it converges uniformly.

Comment: The convergence is *not* uniform on this interval. And the n-th root of the absolute "price" (? absolute value) of *the sequence* being less than 1 is *not* sufficient for the convergence of the *series* (you must look at the *limit* of this $n$-th root). Anyway, this is a (multi!)duplicate.

Comment: so let's say the the series converges to a function f. How can I prove that this function has a continuous derivative in the interval given. Excuse any error as english is not my native language

Comment: For this *new* question, since you already received an answer for the original question (which should moreover be soon closed as a duplicate), please edit a new post, and include your attempts.

Comment: Again, rose, please don't change your question after receiving an answer (and a link), but create a new post if you have a new question. I rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

Using D'almbert
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{\sqrt{n+1}(\tan(x))^{n+1}}{\sqrt n (\tan x)^n}|=| \tan x |$$

we have $x\in]\frac{-\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}[:|\tan x|<1 \implies \text{series}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt n \tan^n x \text{ 
 convergence}$